# How can I use a VBA macro on an excel form (used by multiple people) to send a completed form as a PDF attachment from dynamic Gmail accounts

Tags: excel, vba, gmail

I have created a form for the use of our less tech-savvy field supervisors.  It is a form that they have to manually fax us and it usually arrives much later than what we need in the administrative office that I work at.  I was wanting to use this new excel form to assist them with effectively completing the form and using a single button command to create a new PDF and Excel file with a dynamic name (based on sheet name) and to automatically send it as an email through their company gmail account.

I have successfully managed to create the dynamic sheet name and creation of the PDF and new Excel document, but I cannot seem to find a way to use gmail as a way to email said PDF.  The only sources I can find regarding it seem to limit it to one specific email address that can be used to send it.  I need to find a way to have it be dynamic since we have dozens of different people that would use this form.

Comment: Connect your Gmail account to outlook. Now use vba to send email via outlook. Way easier.

Comment: It might be easier overall, but the powers-that-be want it to be sent directly from Gmail due partially at least to the fact that not all of our field team uses outlook.  I think they are wanting more people to utilize the google accounts in general.  I just need a way for it to be dynamic and not limited to one set email address in the code.

Comment: Right, but if you send them from outlook, people in the field can still receive them on gmail. Anyway, show us the code you've tried and we can see if we can get it to do multiple addresses.

Comment: Oh, "From Dynamic addresses", my mistake.

Comment: I might take a look into removing the vba aspect and looking into google sheets. [**Here is a good place to start looking**](https://spreadsheet.dev/send-email-from-google-sheets)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.